# How to automatically scale inline TikZ code in subscripts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, scaling

I want to use inline TikZ code to create my own subscript symbol. For example something like

```
$V_{\tikz{ \draw [|->] (0,0) -- (2ex,0); }}$
```

The problem is that it is not scaled. The length of the arrow is longer than 2 times the character `x` (`ex` means the height of character `x`). How can I fix this? The problem becomes really painful, if the symbol is a subscript of a subscript. TikZ doesn't scale the symbol although the absolute height of `ex` changes.

I don't want to use a 'standard' math symbol. Actually, my symbol is more complicated and no mathematical symbol is available.

Comment: You can start with using `em` instead of `ex`. Also arrow head size is often related to the line width hence you can also make it depend on the font size. Something like `$V_{\tikz[line width=1/3em]{\draw[|->] (0,0) -- (0.5em,0);}}$`

Comment: Thx for your help but it won't work. Here an example:

    $V_{\tikz[line width=1/3em]{\draw[|->] (0,0) -- (0.5em,0);}}$

    $\frac{1}{V_{\tikz[line width=1/3em]{\draw[|->] (0,0) -- (0.5em,0);}}}$

"V" is scaled properly but not the Tikz symbol.

Comment: You can use amsmath’s `\text` macro to get the correct scaling of the font units (`em` and `ex`), still the line width is fixed and so are the arrows (including some fixed lengths like `2pt`). I think one need to declare new arrows that are based on font units or  scale the resulting `\tikz` with `\resizebox` and `\mathchoice` or `\mathpalette`.

Comment: Could you show your “actual symbol”? Maybe there is a better choice than using TikZ.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: This was the solution. The inline Tikz code must be encapsulated by "\text{}" for correct scaling. I have drawn the arrow head with a simple filled, triangle node. It works like a charm and looks great! Thx!!!

Answer (score 3):

The macro `\text` from the `amstext` (also loaded by `amsmath`) package sets up the correct font sizes and can used to correctly access the font units `em` and `ex`.

From your comments, it seems as if you have used font-size-based nodes for the arrows instead of using real arrows (which is probably not a bad idea because TikZ is very inflexible when it comes to arrow sizes), however I have included a small redefinition of the `|` arrow tip that takes one option (set with `\pgfsetarrowoptions` and accessed with `\pgfgetarrowoptions`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amstext}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myarrow}{%
    \mathchoice
        {\pgfsetarrowoptions{:}{2pt}\my@arrow}
        {\pgfsetarrowoptions{:}{2pt}\my@arrow}
        {\pgfsetarrowoptions{:}{1pt}\my@arrow}
        {\pgfsetarrowoptions{:}{1pt}\my@arrow}
}
\newcommand*{\my@arrow}{\text{\tikz\draw[:->] (0,0) -- (2ex,0);}}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{:}{:}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-0.25\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.75\pgflinewidth}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima\pgfgetarrowoptions{:}
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by0\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetrectcap
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.25\pgflinewidth}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.25\pgflinewidth}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\myarrow\textstyle\myarrow V_{\myarrow_{\myarrow}}$
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]